# Dynamically change element height when resizing viewport

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Is it possible to change the height of an HTML element when the viewport resizes with pure CSS? It's hard to explain the problem, but I'm still going to try:

What I want, is a page with a header, content and a footer, like most webpages. As I'm working with a 1920x1080 monitor, I'm using that as my standard. The problem however is that not everyone is using a 1080p monitor. Some are using the older standard, 1280x1024 or using a tablet where the height can be 2560px (I'm not doing smartphones, as they will have a completely different design due to the small screen width). On my page I have images, covering a fixed width. If this width is greater than the width of the viewport, the images will be displayed underneath each other:
[image]
(Right-click on the image and select "show image" to view at full size)

As you can see in this image, when the viewport is smaller, the images will stack and will fall from the background. The 'Follow me on:' section even felt of entirely. What I want to do is, when this happens, to make the content div larger, so all of the content stays on the page. I know this is possible using `height: auto`, but when you do that, the fixed height of the footer will follow after it, and on a screen with a large height, there might be a white border because the document height is smaller than the viewport height.

Answer (score 0):

Take some time to learn `min-width`, `min-height`, `max-width`, `max-height`, (css attributes) and  `device-width`, `device-height` (css default values of the client viewports). I can not guarantee they would refresh while you drag/resize the browser window or viewports in devices, but I think they help your style rules.

Answer (score 0):

It's slightly unclear to me what your end-goal is with this so I did my best interpretation.  If it's not what you're looking for, give me a good mental image of what you're trying to do and I'll try to correct it.

### [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HqVrP/)

### CSS:

```
html, body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#wrap {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
#header, #content, #footer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
#header {
    top: 0;
    height: 70px;
    background: lightblue;
}
#content {
    overflow-y: auto;
    top: 70px;
    bottom: 70px;
    background: limegreen;
}
#footer {
    bottom: 0;
    height: 70px;
    background: purple;
}
```

### HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="header">Header</div>
    <div id="content">Content</div>
    <div id="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: And if you're wondering whether having no content will give the same window-filling result as the many lines of filler text I put, it will work just the same.

Comment: It's hard to explain this. I edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Looks like you just want to be able to size down the browser and keep whatever is there at it's biggest size, even if it's smaller.  If you can make me a jsfiddle or jsbin with those actual images being used and the rest of your code included, I should be able to show you the route you'll wanna take fairly easily.